# CSS Circle with numbers inside. Displaying as oval rather than circle

Tags: css

I am hoping someone can help me understand why my page-link class isn't producing a proper circle?

Please see the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ts59108v/

I would like the following css class to produce a circle, rather than an oval:

```
.page-link {
    font-style: normal;
    width: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #bdbdbd;
    margin-right: 8px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You tried to set the width of a `span`, which is not possible unless you use `display: inline-block;` on it. Guess the answers below will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/dQR9T/2637/

```
.numberCircle {
border-radius: 50%;
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
/* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
padding: 8px;
background: #fff;
border: 2px solid #666;
color: #666;
text-align: center;
font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `inline-block` to `.page-link`.

[image]

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9cn5pkf1/)